# Mystery flash of code displayed on page load

Tags: google-chrome

I have a screen full of code that displays for about half a second on loading some pages in chrome.

I managed to grab a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dOGU.gif) of it.
I think this one is from a google search for the London tube map.

[image: Code generated on page load using chrome]

I have disabled chrome extensions and antivirus but it still appears.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Try using your CMD or terminal to tracert a couple websites and see if  there is anything suspicious happening on your HTTP request.

Comment: Tried a few sites and nothing suspicious listed.

Comment: What about in other browsers and in incognito mode?

Comment: It has only appeared in Chrome. I haven't monitored it in incognito mode yet. I will try it for the rest of the day and see if the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular instance the code is generated by [Bitdefender Traffic Light extension](http://www.bitdefender.com/solutions/trafficlight.html). If the antivirus is installed, the extension seems to be enabled without being displayed in Chrome's list of extensions.

Disabling the antivirus doesn't seem to disable the extension. But you can clearly see it is activated in a google search as each link has a specific icon next to it.[image: trafficlight icon]

Other extensions might do a similar thing, but in the lower-left part of the screenshot, the code is:

```
fraud_link = "http://trafficlight.bitdefender.com/info?url={URL}&language=en_US";
```

Which makes it obvious this extention is causing the code to be displayed.